# Different versions of same lib broke my package manager

Tags: debian, nvidia, multiarch

```
OS: Debian stretch
linux kernel: 4.7.0-1-amd64
```

I have unmet dependencies between some nvidia packages. They seem to be caused by `libnvidia-glcore` and `libnvidia-eglcore` Forcing them through apt/dpkg/aptitude doesn't seem to work. `apt-get install -f` gives me this output:

```
root@debdesk:~# apt-get upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libslang2 libslang2-dev linux-headers-4.7.0-1-amd64
  linux-headers-4.7.0-1-common linux-image-4.7.0-1-amd64
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnvidia-eglcore libnvidia-glcore
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/12.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 251496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libnvidia-glcore_367.44-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-glcore:amd64 (367.44-2) over (352.79-10~bpo8+2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-sOf2cJ/0-libnvidia-glcore_367.44-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/bug/libnvidia-glcore/script', which is different from other instances of package libnvidia-glcore:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../1-libnvidia-eglcore_367.44-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-eglcore:amd64 (367.44-2) over (352.79-10~bpo8+2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-sOf2cJ/1-libnvidia-eglcore_367.44-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-eglcore/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libnvidia-eglcore:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-sOf2cJ/0-libnvidia-glcore_367.44-2_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-sOf2cJ/1-libnvidia-eglcore_367.44-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt-cache policy libnvidia-glcore libnvidia-glcore:i386` prints the following:

```
libnvidia-glcore:
  Installed: 352.79-10~bpo8+2
  Candidate: 367.44-2
  Version table:
     367.44-2 500
        500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Packages
 *** 352.79-10~bpo8+2 100
        100 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/non-free amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libnvidia-glcore:i386:
  Installed: 367.44-2
  Candidate: 367.44-2
  Version table:
 *** 367.44-2 500
        500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     352.79-10~bpo8+2 100
        100 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports/non-free i386 Packages
```

Some time ago I tried to install some packages from the experimental branch and I left the source saved in the sources file. I've been using the nvidia-driver build fetched from jessie-backports. Here is what`/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux stretch-DI-alpha7 _Stretch_ - Official Snapshot amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160630-14:29]/ stretch main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux stretch-DI-alpha7 _Stretch_ - Official Snapshot amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160630-14:29]/ stretch main

deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian experimental main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

I can't purge nor reinstall the installation because of those dependencies.

What can I do?

edit:

output of `apt-get purge libnvidia-eglcore libnvidia-glcore`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl-nvidia0 : Depends: libnvidia-eglcore (= 367.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-nvidia-glx : Depends: libnvidia-glcore (= 367.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
 libgles-nvidia1 : Depends: libnvidia-eglcore (= 367.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
 libgles-nvidia2 : Depends: libnvidia-eglcore (= 367.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
 libglx-nvidia0 : Depends: libnvidia-glcore (= 367.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-driver-libs : Depends: libnvidia-glcore (= 367.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: nvidia-driver-libs-i386
 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia : Depends: libnvidia-glcore (= 367.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
                             Recommends: nvidia-settings (>= 367) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: The technical term for what you have here is a mess. It's probably fixable, but it's not worth anyone's time. I suggest you reinstall. I don't understand "I can't purge nor reinstall the installation because of those dependencies." What do you mean?

Comment: Just for the hell of it, what does "apt-get purge  libnvidia-eglcore libnvidia-glcore" give? Or try purging the packages individually. Output in the question, not in comments, please.

Comment: Yeah, it's a huge mess ): It doesn't seem like I can use the package manager any more because no matter what I do I get redirected to the error and nothing happens.

Comment: Damn that was so silly, I've read the output of apt-get purge again since you asked for it and tried to remove all the dependencies one by one. First time I did that, it would spit even more dependencies so I thought that wasn't the way to follow, but I kept doing it and managed to fix it. Now I'm trying to cut with the multi repos for this particular case. Such a silly question, yet so much to learn. I always ask silly stuff, thank you for your time though; I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you managed to fix your problem, post an answer. It might be useful for someone else later.

Comment: I tend to just leave it in the comments but since my issue was about certain packages I'll try to reach a resolution these days and post everything here. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I finally purged the whole nvidia thing and managed to install a completely new set of packages.

I had to manually purge the packages that were giving me the error dependencies and then I had some issues with residual libs and configs that were still installed after purging `nvidia-*` through `apt-get`, so I also made sure to remove everything that fell under `libnvidia-*` regex, which didn't look like it would break anything after reading what would get uninstalled.

After that I rebooted and made sure I cleared any temporal or residual package and files, installed the nvidia drivers using the jessie-backports deb I have in `/etc/apt/sourceslist` (manually fixing dependencies myself and avoiding aptitude to take care of them) and everything now werks. Thanks dr greenthumb, you're the shit